# Android SDK. Append audio file. MediaPlayer, AudioRecord, etc

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-2.2-froyo, android-audiomanager

Is it possible to append an already existing .3gp audio file using MediaRecorder, AudioRecord, or the third method I forgot about?

SoundRecorder, SoundPlayer, audiomanager or something like that...

I just need to know if it's possible and what class I should use.

Thanks,